# splitting text data in mysql

Tags: mysql, split, delimiter

i want to split my row something like this:

example:

```
id  data
1   23#4#
2   2#4#5#
```

to be like this

```
id  data
1   23
1   4
2   2
2   4
2   5
```

i have looking for this problem in stack overflow but the solution is not satisfaction me. please help me.

i try to make a store procedure in mysql, the code it's ok no error, but the result is not ok.

```
drop procedure if exists pecah_lokasi_sp;
create procedure pecah_lokasi_sp()
begin   
    DECLARE ii INT;
    DECLARE ki varchar(255);
    DECLARE ulang int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE hasil varchar(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE selesai INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id_iklan, lokasi_kerja_utama
        FROM iklan_lowongan_tb
        WHERE status = 'Aktif'; 

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET selesai = TRUE;

    DELETE FROM temp_lok_tb;

    OPEN kursor;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH kursor INTO ii, ki;   

        IF selesai  THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        WHILE (ulang < LENGTH(ki)) DO
            IF SUBSTRING(ki, ulang, 1) <> '#' THEN
                SET hasil = CONCAT(hasil, SUBSTRING(ki, ulang, 1));             
            ELSE    
                INSERT INTO temp_lok_tb (id_iklan, id_kota) VALUES(ii, hasil);
                SET hasil = '';             
            END IF;
            SET ulang = ulang+1;
        END WHILE;
        SET ulang = 1;
    END LOOP read_loop; 

    CLOSE kursor;
    select * from temp_lok_tb;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i can solve my problem myself.
this is my revision code, the result is true.

```
drop procedure if exists pecah_lokasi_sp;
```

create procedure pecah_lokasi_sp()
begin
    DECLARE ii INT;
    DECLARE ki varchar(255);
    DECLARE ulang int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE hasil varchar(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE selesai INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE jmlkarakter int;

```
DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id_iklan, lokasi_kerja_utama
    FROM iklan_lowongan_tb
    WHERE status = 'Aktif'; 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET selesai = TRUE;

DELETE FROM temp_lok_tb;

OPEN kursor;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH kursor INTO ii, ki;   

    IF selesai  THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET jmlkarakter = LENGTH(ki) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ki, '#', '')) ;

    WHILE (ulang <= jmlkarakter) DO

        IF ulang = 1 THEN
            INSERT INTO temp_lok_tb(id_iklan, id_kota) VALUES(ii, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ki,'#',1));
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO temp_lok_tb(id_iklan, id_kota) VALUES(ii, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ki,'#', ulang),'#',-1));
        END IF;

        SET ulang = ulang+1;
    END WHILE;

    SET ulang = 1;
END LOOP read_loop; 

CLOSE kursor;
select * from temp_lok_tb;
```

end;